# While loop inside if statement confusion

Tags: php, mysql

This has been an ongoing struggle for me for the last four days.  I was really hoping to work this out enough to not have to ask here, because it's a lot of code, but I'm afraid I have tried and tried to reduce the problem down, and it's just like I'm chasing my tail.  I have eliminated as much code as I think I can-I may have eliminated more than I should have to easily see what is going on, so feel free to ask for clarification.

The synopses:

I am pulling a calendar feed from Google calendar and populating my own calendar.  My calendar has added functionality where I have a database of "timeline events" that are like to-do items that happen a certain number of days (`DaysFromEvent`) from the regular event.

The feed gets pulled in by this cron and searches for any new events on the google calendar and adds them to the database.  (This part seems to be working as it should).  The cron also looks at the `ModifiedInGoogle` field to see if the event has been modified and if so it updates the event in the database.  That also seems to be working.  The crux is that if the main event is modified, then I also need to look in the database and pull any timeline event that is associated with the main event and change its start time based on `StartTime + DaysFromEvent`

I think I pretty much have this script doing that, but I seem to be having trouble with my `while` loop that is inside of the `if` statement.

When I run a modified event through the script, I only get echoed up to the point of: `echo "Event ID: ".$tempEventID. ", Promotional Time Line: ".$tempTimelineID.", Parent Event ID: ".$tempParentEventID."<br>";`

I should be getting am echo from the while loop, but I'm not.  My apologies for the long words, and even more apologies for the long code to follow.  I'm a newbie at this, so please be gentle. :)

I'm about ready to give up and hire someone to finish this for me because I'm a musician not a programmer!

```
if((int)$feed->totalResults>0)  { //checking if at least one event is there in this date range

    foreach ($feed as $event) { //iterating through all events and pulling all the info to assign the variables below.

        $UserID= "42";
        $eventDatabase = "events";  

        //Setting startDate and startTime and endDate and endTime
        $StartDate = $event->when[0]->startTime;
        $date = strtotime($StartDate);
        $StartDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$date);
        $StartArray = explode(' ', $StartDate);
        $StartTime = $StartArray[1];
        $EndDate = $event->when[0]->endTime;
        $date = strtotime($EndDate);
        $EndDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$date);
        $EndArray = explode(' ', $EndDate);
        $EndTime = $EndArray[1];  

        $ModifiedInGoogle = $event->updated->text;
        $GoogleID = $event->id;

        $EventName = stripslashes($event->title);
        $PromotionalTimeLine = "0";
        $ParentEventID = "NULL";
        $DaysFromEvent = "";


        //We are seeing if the Event is already in the database by looking for the googleID
        $query = "SELECT * FROM ".$eventDatabase. " WHERE GoogleID='$GoogleID'";
        $result = mysql_query($query);

        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);

        //This loop UPDATES events if ModifiedInGoogle string is different than what is already in the database
        if($ModifiedInGoogle != $row['ModifiedInGoogle']){

            //Variables for modifying the timeline start time
            $ModifiedEventStartTime = $row['StartTime'];
            $tempParentEventID = $tempEventID = $row['EventID'];
            $tempTimelineID = $row['PromotionalTimeLine'];

            //THIS ECHOS AS I EXPECT IT SHOULD
            echo "Event ID: ".$tempEventID. ", Promotional Time Line: ".$tempTimelineID.", Parent Event ID: ".$tempParentEventID."<br>";

            //Updates main event when modified in google:
             mysql_query("UPDATE ".$eventDatabase." SET 
             EventName = '$EventName', 
             StartDate = '$StartDate', 
             StartTime = '$StartTime', 
             EndTime = '$EndTime', 
             EndDate = '$EndDate', 
             Description = '$Description', 
             AllDay = '$AllDay', 
             CreatedOn = '$CreatedOn', 
             GoogleID = '$GoogleID', 
             ModifiedInGoogle = '$ModifiedInGoogle'

             WHERE GoogleID='$GoogleID' ");

            //Query to select the timeline events that have the same ParentEvenID-this is where everything seems to start falling apart...
            $query = "SELECT * FROM events WHERE ParentEventID='.$tempParentEventID.' AND GoogleID IS NULL";
            $tempresult = mysql_query($query);

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($tempresult, MYSQL_ASSOC)){

            $tempEventID = $row['EventID'];
            $tempDaysFromEvent = $row['DaysFromEvent'];
            $tempStartDate = $row['StartDate'];

            //THIS LINE IS NOT ECHOING
            echo "EventID: ".$tempEventID.", Start Date: ".$tempStartDate.", Days From Event: ".$tempDaysFromEvent.", Parent Event ID: ".$row['ParentEventID']."<br>";

            //IF STARTDATE IS DIFFERENT FROM HOW IT USED TO BE, UPDATE IT.
            list($year, $month, $day) = explode("-", $tempStartDate);
            $tempStartDate      =   $tempEndDate    =    date("Y-m-d", mktime (0,0,0,$month,$day+$tempDaysFromEvent,$year));
            echo "TempStart Date:".$tempStartDate."<br>";

            //Query to update the startdate of the events
            mysql_query("UPDATE".$eventDatabase." SET
            StartDate = '$tempStartDate'
            WHERE EventID = $tempEventID
            ");
        }  //Closes While loop


        }  //This closes the update if modified if statement

    //This loop adds NEW EVENTS
    if (!mysql_num_rows($result)) {

    //Insert NEW EVENTS

    }
} //ends main event loop
} else  { 

  echo "No event found";
}
```

Comment: I would expect that not to echo out if your query (`$query`) just above it returned no results.

Comment: Just to be clear, it's not just the echo on that one line (there should be 2 echos in that block) - but the entire `while` block that's not doing anything, correct?

Comment: Could you make it as minimal as possible? With only the echo maybe, and no other code? that would be more helpful then just apologizing for the long code ;)

Comment: I would suggest that you echo out the update query and check if it can be run manually.

Comment: @Wesly-yes-the echo statements in the while loop are not echoing but the echo statement in the if statement above it is echoing.  It's my assumption that if the if statement runs, the while statement will also run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Within the line

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM events WHERE ParentEventID='.$tempParentEventID.' AND GoogleID IS NULL";
```

You have included single quotes instead of doubles. Did you mean to have

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM events WHERE ParentEventID=".$tempParentEventID." AND GoogleID IS NULL";
```

or maybe without the dots (if you want to keep the delimiters)

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM events WHERE ParentEventID='$tempParentEventID' AND GoogleID IS NULL";
```

Comment: In double quotes, you can use a variable inside the quote, so I'd assume the single quotes would be to enclose the variable $temp.ParentEventID in those quotes.

Comment: Yes, but the . on eah side of the variable should not be there. That is a mix of two possible solutiions.

Comment: @Mike good remark, but then the dots should be omitted, see my edit.

Comment: Nice catch, forgot about the dots. Either way, the original doesn't work and your two alternative would, though, it would depend on whether or not the single quote was supposed to be there (if so, the second of your fixes would be the desired one, otherwise, the first would be).

Comment: I've actually been pretty confused about this aspect when writing a query.  So you can either use double quotes and the dots or single quots and no dot is that right?

Comment: That actually really helped-after that fix, I am now at least getting the echos to happen as I expected them to.  Other parts of the code are not yet working right, but that's ok, becaus this big confusion is now taken care of, and I think I can reduce the blocks that I'm dealing with now.  THanks so much!

Comment: Can you comment on wether there is a difference between your second or third aproach and when you would choose one or the other?

Comment: @Joel depends on the type of your column and the content of your variable. Generally speaking if you have a char column you must include the quotes (if not already contained in your variable), thus the second option. If your column instead is numeric you won't want the quotes.

Answer (score -1):

Well the first thing that jumps out at me is the while loop:
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($tempresult, MYSQL_ASSOC))

in order for the while loop to continue the argument must be "true". I'm not too familiar with php and some language accept any integer larger than 0 to not be false, but that may be a source of error.

Comment: I get a downvote for pointing out a possible source of error first before other people post the exact same thing?

Comment: In this case, the only time the while loop should be running is if the if statement above it is true.

Answer (score -1):

It says:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($tempresult, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
```

Shouldn't it be:

```
while($row == mysql_fetch_array($tempresult, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
```

If that's not the intent, then there seems to be something fishy with that, because you won't get a proper value from an action, you'll need a query of some kind.